# Uncaught (in promise) Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

My application doesn't recognize my route even that I already defined it and imported in `app.module`.

When receiving the data, I redirect to this but I have always this exception:

```
onSubmit(){
    this.transactionService.createTransactionIfNotExist(this.video).subscribe(
      transaction => this.router.navigate([transaction.currentStep.action, this.video.id, transaction.token ]));
  }

transaction.currentStep.action = PreviewStep
this.video.id = 1
transaction.token = f54db125-ca01-4afc-b714-76c127abb261
```

and the exception

> ```
> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'PreviewStep/1/f54db125-ca01-4afc-b714-76c127abb261'
> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'PreviewStep/1/f54db125-ca01-4afc-b714-76c127abb261'
> ```

**transaction.routing**

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
   { path: 'previewStep/:videoId/:transactionId', component: PreviewStepComponent }
]);
```

**transaction.module**

```
import { PreviewStepComponent } from "./components/preview-step/preview-step.component";
import { routing } from './transaction.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule, routing, FormsModule, SharedModule, RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: [PreviewStepComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class TransactionModule { }
```

**app.module**

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { TransactionModule } from './transaction/transaction.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    TransactionModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Your route is defined as `previewStep` but you're trying to access `PreviewStep`

Comment: ah, I don't know that route name is case sensitive. I will check it. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, angular routing name is case sensitive.

That means we must change `PreviewStep` to `previewStep` to match the route name.

To override this situation, either changer the route name or create a `UrlSerializer`.

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

export class TitleCaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {  
    public parse(url: string): UrlTree {
        function toTitleCase(url) {
            return url.split('/')
                       .map(segment => segment ? 
                                       segment[0].toUpperCase() + segment.substr(1) : 
                                       segment)
                       .join('/');
        }
        return super.parse(toTitleCase(url));
    }
}

@NgModule({
   imports: [ ... ],
   declarations: [ ... ],
   providers: [
        {
            provide: UrlSerializer,
            useClass: TitleCaseUrlSerializer
        }
   ]
})
```